# Acumatica 2020R1 - FirstOrDefault selecting a different row

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have used FirstOrDefault a ton in my code (its a habit, I used linq2sql a lot in the past) and use it in Acumatica. Per development support, it should only be used when you are expecting one result.

I have some code on SOOrderEntry that gets the item on the current line by clicking a button and checking a few things. This is in my Graph Extension.

This code worked prior to the upgrade:

```
SOLine Line = Base.Transactions.Current;
InventoryItem Item = SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(Base, Line.InventoryID).FirstOrDefault();                
InventoryItemExt ItemExt = Item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

The result is not as expected. Line.InventoryID returns 10045, which is the correct item. Item.InventoryID is 10046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, I found that the new argument that can be used easily is the new property TopFirst. This returns the First Result.

The following code works as expected (and how it worked in 2019 R2 and before!).

```
SOLine Line = Base.Transactions.Current;
InventoryItem Item = SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(Base, Line.InventoryID).TopFirst;                
InventoryItemExt ItemExt = Item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

Comment: The issue is that FirstOrDefault isn't part of Acumatica and therefore has no notion of database sort order. It's contract is to return the first valid element in a dotnet collection not the first ordered record from database.

Comment: That is correct. Per a previous case I had opened due to that issue in the past, "FirstOrDefault is typically used in case where only one record is expected". Those cases that were only expecting one record are no longer, than this fix was needed.

Comment: Also, it is still used in the Code Repository, PX.Objects.PM.PMQuoteMaintExt, VisibilityHandler: 

CR.Standalone.CROpportunityRevision revisionInDb = PXSelectReadonly<CR.Standalone.CROpportunityRevision,
    Where<CR.Standalone.CROpportunityRevision.noteID, Equal<Required<CR.Standalone.CROpportunityRevision.noteID>>>>.Select(Base, row.QuoteID).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I think same rule applies here, it can cause issue only when sort order is important. Using Top does take into account sort at DB level which has different behavior.